# How can I write the service tag in the manifest if it is in a sub class activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

If I have a class (Activity) and a service like this case, how can I write the service tag in the manifest?

```
public class TestA extends Activity {

    public class TestB extends Service {

    }
}
```

I know if the service is alone (not within an Activity), I can write it this way:

```
<service android:name="ThePackageName.TestB" ></service>
```

But in my case I don't know how to write it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
<service android:name="ThePackageName.TestA.TestB" ></service>
```

Comment: hey QBY , was it useful for you ?

Comment: I think its right, because i was having problem when i ran my program... but still can't fix my problem with updating widget using service :(.. some people recommend for me to use the service for updating the widget(manual).. but still it won't work... but in general, your answer should fix some of the problem before i was facing it :)  Thanks alot ;)

Answer (score 0):

try `<service android:name="TestA$TestB" ></service>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<activity android:name=".TestA" android:label="Testing"> </activity>

<service android:name="YourPackage.TestA.TestB"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <service android:name=".FirstService" 
           android:enabled="true"></service>
```